# Creating MediaStream Object in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc, media-source

As far as I know the MediaStream object is return from getUserMedia but is there a way to create a MediaStream object from a local .mp4 or .webm file? (or any other hack-ish way)

Looking into this to in an attempt to automate some testing that's pretty specific to need this.

Edit: This is Chrome specific. There's currently a canvas operation in Firefox that does what I would need but it's not on Chrome (yet?)

Edit 2: This is what is used for Firefox 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream

Is there anything equivalent for Chrome? or is there really no way to re-create a MediaSteam object some other way . . .

Right now the only thing I can think of is to use this on Firefox for a webrtc peerconnection to send it over to a chrome peerconnection and hope that stream received is valid.

Comment: Last little comment on this. The canvas capture is currently in Chrome Canary V50, available with the flag "Experimental Web Platform Features". Hopefully this gets into stable Chrome soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Media Capture from DOM Elements](http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-fromelement/), there are two methods, `captureStreamUntilEnded` and `captureStream` that should work on both HTML media elements(audio and video) and the HTML canvas element.

Like you said, firefox has been supporting capturing canvas for some time, but unfortunately for chrome, it is still [work in progress](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=524218), you could star the issue and follow for updates.

Comment: thank you! Seems I need to do the work around for now.

Comment: @JerryFox what are you trying to achieve, based on that I could suggest some workaround

Comment: See [Intent to Ship: Media Capture from Canvas](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/mOWCmoEFfS8/VHYbbaohDQAJ). It seems to already be supported in Chrome 50 dev/canary, so I think that Intent to Ship indicates it will be included in the Chrome 50 stable release, which is [targeted for Apr 19th, 2016](http://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar#TOC-Estimated-Stable-Dates). It may even already be in Chrome 49 ([stable release targeted for Mar 8th, 2016](http://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar#TOC-Estimated-Stable-Dates).